# How to explain an extension of a certification

Tags: word-usage

The international branches of the company I work for was awarded with new quality standards. The Italian Headquarters already had these certifications, hence these were extended to the branches. What's the noun for extension with regard to this topic? Is it correct to say:

> Extension of the certification to the international branches

I'm not sure if *extension* is the right word to use here.

Comment: Standards aren't generally awarded; they're imposed or applied. If headquarters had met the standards and was certified to have done so, it's unlikely that the certification would be extended to the international branches. The requirement to meet the standards might be so extended, but the branches would have to get their own certifications of compliance.

Comment: Extension would be correct.  The certificate of compliance for the HQ would be reissued with extension to certify the branches.

Answer (score 1):

The certifications used at headquarters were **adopted** by the rest of the company.

> [to adopt](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adopt): Choose to take up or follow (an idea, method, or course of action):
>   *‘this approach has been adopted by many big banks’*

*(Oxford)*

Comment: Uh… no way, Jose. 'Standards' can happily be 'adopted' by anyone, anywhere at any time. In any relevant sense 'certifications' can only be awarded or received.

The only way certification could be adopted would be if a jurisdiction - a country or an industry, for instance - started to use that certification to measure standards and even then, it would more likely be 'standards' that were adopted.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I see it now.  I'm going to try again and then delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The certifications *granted* (or *awarded*) to HQ *applied to* (or *spanned*) the other branches as well.

noun: *extension of scope*, or just *extension*

Or, a fun way to say this, from the opposite point of view, is that the other branches *inherited* headquarters' certification, or *piggybacked* on headquarters' certification.